# Removing $id from web api response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-5.0

I have a web api 5.0 which returns a dto of a pretty basic object. Here is the class

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = false)] 
public class BillToReturnDto
{
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public string organizationId { get; set; } 

}
```

but when I return a list of it it returns like this

{
"$id": "1",
"$values": [
{
"$id": "2",
"id": "rvKLS178QWyWJu0tgESTnA",
"organizationId": "ujoF624LSVyyQFapjauyAw",
},
{
"$id": "2",
"id": "xvWfrRQWyyG0tgEd53dW",
"organizationId": "ujoF624LSVyyQFapjauyAw",
}
]
}

How would it be possible to remove those ids? I've tried IsReference false as you can see to no avail

Update:

Here's the controller method:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
    {
        var userId = User.FindFirst("Id").Value;
        var accessToken = await _userService.GetAccessToken(Convert.ToInt32(userId));
        var bills = await _shoppingService.GetBills(accessToken);
        var billsToReturn = _mapper.Map<List<BillToReturnDto>>(bills.bills);
        return Ok(billsToReturn);
    }
```

Comment: Show us the controller please 
which returns the result

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada I have done that in an update thx

Comment: you using asp.neet core ? or mvc just to be sure

Comment: Im using the new 5.0, it's essentially core but they've removed core from its name

Comment: most recent is core 3.X

Comment: if you are using asp .net mvc put this at WebApiConfig.cs

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada I am using this: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0

Comment: It's simple web api from 5.0

Comment: WebApiConfig.cs dose your project has this Page WebApiConfig.cs  ?

Answer (score 3):

This line in startup.cs could created the issue in my case:

```
   services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
                });
```

Remove the .AddJsonOptions([....]) and see if it works for you to.

Comment: Perfect working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change in Program.cs (.NET 6) or Startup.cs (.NET 5):

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
           {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = 
                ReferenceHandler.Preserve;
            });
```

To:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
               {
                    options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = 
                    ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're using .NET Core 3.1 through 5.0 (currently the latest), then install the following NuGet package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/ )

***It exposes a new property called ReferenceLoopHandling, which can be used to remove the $id references in your Web API .JSON responses.***

Next, in your Startup class, append the following to the services.AddControllers() line:

```
// add controllers and the newtonsoft option to not include a reference $id
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
   options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

...and now try it...

Answer (score 0):

We are using Newtonsof with odata haveing same issue after migrating to .net 6:

```
            services.AddControllers(options => options.MaxIAsyncEnumerableBufferLimit = 524288)
            .AddOData(options => options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().SetMaxTop(null).AddRouteComponents("odata", new OdataModelBuilder().GetEdmModel()).TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
        services.AddODataQueryFilter();
```

Any help here please? I am not sure if it's safe to chnage *Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects* to *Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None*...